# Run JS function on document load and when a certain element is clicked [Tampermonkey]

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I'm trying to write a Tampermonkey script to extend a business web app I use. In a very basic sense, certain URL's appear on the page, I need to extract a number from the URL then use than number to build a new link and append to the parent element.

So far I have this but it's not working when I click on the element (pagination just an UL) or on document load. I know the function works as when I set it to run on clicking anywhere in the document it works. It's almost like the page isn't fully loaded when JS reports it is loaded.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    //get the pagination element
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName('pagination-sm');
    element.onclick = createLinks;
    document.onload = createLinks;

    function createLinks() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll ("a[href*='/Field/POPendingCreate/']");

        for (var J = links.length-1; J >= 0; --J) {
            var thisLink = links[J];
            console.log(thisLink.href);
            var ppon = thisLink.href.match(/\d+/)[0];
            console.log(ppon);

            var a = document.createElement('a');
            var linkText = document.createTextNode("Preview Order");
            a.appendChild(linkText);
            a.title = "Preview Order";
            a.href = "https://website.com/Field/DownloadPendingPO?POPPKeyID=" + ppon + "&co=1&po=" + ppon;
            a.target = "_blank";

            var parentNode = thisLink.parentNode;
            console.log(parentNode);
            parentNode.appendChild(a);

        }
    }

 })();
```

The UL element just looks like this:

```
<ul uib-pagination="" items-per-page="formData.itemPerPage" class="pagination-sm ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ng-isolate-scope pagination ng-not-empty" data-total-items="pendingList.length" data-ng-model="formData.currentPage" data-max-size="10" data-ng-if="!attachmentView &amp;&amp; filteredDocuments.length > 0" role="menu"><!-- ngIf: ::boundaryLinks -->
<!-- ngIf: ::directionLinks --><li role="menuitem" ng-if="::directionLinks" ng-class="{disabled: noPrevious()||ngDisabled}" class="pagination-prev ng-scope disabled"><a href="" ng-click="selectPage(page - 1, $event)" ng-disabled="noPrevious()||ngDisabled" uib-tabindex-toggle="" class="ng-binding" disabled="disabled" tabindex="-1">Previous</a></li><!-- end ngIf: ::directionLinks -->
<!-- ngRepeat: page in pages track by $index --><li role="menuitem" ng-repeat="page in pages track by $index" ng-class="{active: page.active,disabled: ngDisabled&amp;&amp;!page.active}" class="pagination-page ng-scope active"><a href="" ng-click="selectPage(page.number, $event)" ng-disabled="ngDisabled&amp;&amp;!page.active" uib-tabindex-toggle="" class="ng-binding">1</a></li><!-- end ngRepeat: page in pages track by $index -->
<!-- ngIf: ::directionLinks --><li role="menuitem" ng-if="::directionLinks" ng-class="{disabled: noNext()||ngDisabled}" class="pagination-next ng-scope disabled"><a href="" ng-click="selectPage(page + 1, $event)" ng-disabled="noNext()||ngDisabled" uib-tabindex-toggle="" class="ng-binding" disabled="disabled" tabindex="-1">Next</a></li><!-- end ngIf: ::directionLinks -->
<!-- ngIf: ::boundaryLinks -->
</ul>
```

As I said above the function works as expected when I set it to run on clicking anywhere on the document. More puzzling to me is that it doesn't work when using document.onload. It's like the page only starts loading data in once I start interacting with it. The reason why I'm trying to have the function run when clicking on the pagination is because the page appears to get all the data and store it somewhere (I can't see) then just flicks through the pages when paginating. So once the pagination is clicked I really need to run the function on the links that are generated on the new page.

Seems like I need to delay running document.onload or some other way of knowing once the document data has loaded and also work out why it won't run when clicking on the UL pagination element?

Comment: One problem immediately springs to mind: `getElementsByClassName` returns a node _list_. You can't assign a listener to a list. Either use `forEach` and attach a listener to each node or if it's just one node maybe use `querySelector` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of waiting for the page to render and then looping through all the elements to attach an anchor tag. Just use a MutationObserver to handle any elements that get rendered after you have run your logic.

**JS**

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    const createLinks = function ( nodeElement ){
        const queryElem = nodeElement.parentElement || nodeElement;
        const links = queryElem.querySelectorAll("a[href*='/Field/POPendingCreate/']");

        for ( const link of links || [] ){
            // Skip link if Preview has been attached
            if ( link.createLinkReady ) continue;

            // Get numbers from link href
            const [ ppon ] = link.href.match(/\d+/);

            // Create an anchor tag
            const a = document.createElement('a');
            a.innerHTML = 'Preview Order';
            a.setAttribute( 'title', 'Preview Order' );
            a.setAttribute( 'href', `https://website.com/Field/DownloadPendingPO?POPPKeyID=${ppon}&co=1&po=${ppon}` );
            a.setAttribute( 'target', '_blank' );
            a.setAttribute( 'rel', 'nofollow' );

            // Append anchor tag to parent element
            link.parentElement.appendChild( a );
            link.createLinkReady = true;
        }

    }

    // Create DOM MutationObserver
    const Observer = new MutationObserver( function( mutationsList ) {
        // Loop through mutations
        for ( const mutation of mutationsList || [] ) {
            // Loop through added nodes
            for ( const node of mutation.addedNodes || [] ){
                // Run createLinks on node
                createLinks( node );
            }
        }
    });

    // Observe DOM for new elements starting from document.body
    Observer.observe( document.body, { childList:true, subtree:true } );

    // Process links that have been rendered
    createLinks( document.body );
 })();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this basically worked perfectly. I just had to change querySelectorAll("a[href*='/Field/POPendingCreate/']") to match the urls more specifically so some other links weren't included. This is exactly what I wanted to achieve. Thanks again!

Comment: Perfect. I would also recommend that you use `document.getElementById` or `document.getElementsByClassName` or `document.getElementsByTagName` because they are about 100x more performance efficient than `queryElem.querySelector` or `queryElem.querySelectorAll`

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at those other options, see if I can make them work.